# incorrect IFC geometry in viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

some geometry in IFC files are not correct translated or displayed in the viewer
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8huHq.png)

left is element in Forge viewer, right is same element in Solibri.

I uploaded the IFC file to BIM360 Docs. I want to view it in Forge viewer.

I tried the new viewer prefs (7.19.0) "Prefs3D.FORCE_DOUBLE_SIDED preference that will turn on or off double sided materials." https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/
same result.
I only experience this with IFC files.

any other options I can try?

Comment: Which IFC model format did you upload to Forge? Could you follow the instruction here to use Revit based IFC translation pipeline (`"switchLoader": false`)  instead to see if it helps? https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/model-derivative-ifc-pipeline-call-change

Comment: @EasonKang IFC Format is "IFC4"

We also had the same issue with IFC2X3
We uploaded to BIM360Docs, I dont know wich "switchLoader" they use.
Is the Revit based translation not the default at the moment?

Comment: In BIM360 Docs, Revit based translation is the default option. If the file is IFC4, then it's not supported at this moment.